# Django registration timeout

Tags: django, nginx, django-registration

When submitting the registration form for a new user, the page keeps loading for a long time (30 sec) and finally stops with a timeout (HTTP Code 504). On the development server, it works without any problems.

Neither of the log files (error and access) contains an entry about the form submission (POST request). Only the GET request is logged:

```
gouyen.cli:80 10.65.26.120 - - [13/Mar/2017:18:41:19 +0100] "GET /clfiles/projects/clgeokokos/geokokos/app/register/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3328 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
```

I found out that the web server only writes to the access log if the request has been processed. That must be the reason for not finding a log entry for the POST request. I suspect that, the script gets stuck in an infinite loop when processing the POST request.

Any ideas how to solve this or get some more information about the problem?

Thank you!

The application runs on an nginx 1.6.2 with an apache proxy.

We use the [django registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.2/) (version 2.2) with Django 1.10.3.

Comment: Please paste log from nginx and django

Comment: The only log entry is the one I posted above. What could be the reasons for the page loading for such a long time? Could there be an infinite loop somewhere in the django-registration app?